# My dialog is not being correctly displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-theme, android-dialog

I have created a custom dialog layout and I am trying to display the dialog as a Activity instead of inflating the view inside the alert dialog. But the dialog is not being displayed as desired. Please have a look.

Custom Dialog Layout

[image: Custom Dialog Layout]

The dialog activity is being shown like below

[image: The dialog activity is being shown like below]

You can take a look at the code below

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PROFILE_PHOTO = 1;

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showImageOptionsDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showImageOptionsDialog() {
        Intent imageDialogIntent = new Intent(this, ImageDialogActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(imageDialogIntent, PROFILE_PHOTO);
    }
}
```

ImageDialogActivity

```
public class ImageDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_dialog);
    }
}
```

activity_image_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/sixteen"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".ImageDialogActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/eight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_profile_pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/label_profile_photo"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/option_gallery" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cancel_button_bg"
                android:text="@string/action_cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/option_gallery"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_pick_img"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/eight"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/option_gallery"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/option_remove_pic"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_profile_pic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/option_remove_pic"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_remove_pic"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/eight"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/option_remove_photo"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/option_gallery"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/option_gallery"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ImageDialogActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
```

I'm not able to figure out the issue. Please help. Regards!

Comment: Try using BottomSheetDialogFragment https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: post you code too

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Please add dialog xml code

Comment: I think you should give your width and height in your custom layout xml but you should post your xml file before answering you

Comment: You should give width to match parent for root and other views too.

Answer (score 1):

It is worked for me

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width) / 7, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I tried doing this. But it still shows the layout inside a dialog along with the app title. Moreover, as you can see my aim is to show the dialog at the bottom but this solution is showing it in the center of the screen.

Comment: else use bottom sheet fragment ...

BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this); dialog.setContentView(YourView);

dialog.show();